# Windows Azure Node JS WEBSOCKET HandShake Fails 503 Error

Tags: node.js, azure, http-status-code-503, node.js-client

I've deployed my nodeJS server in windows azure.
My client fails while connecting to server and handle the following error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://ooplrfrfranode.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/1/websocket/lHrd-DOydinODjbS7-tc' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503.
```

Any Help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Windows Azure Web Sites has recently added support for the WebSocket protocol.  Both .NET developers and node.js developers can now enable and use WebSockets in their applications.

There is a new option on a web site’s Configuration tab to enable WebSockets support for an application.

[image]

Source: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: When I turn it on, I got this error `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`. Any idea?

Comment: can you print the full stacktrace please ?

Answer (score 5):

## For students struggling with socket.io on Azure

I've struggled for 2 days with this. I was using a student free tier for the service app and apparently that was part of the problem.

I made a `B1 plan` app service with my student credits. After uploading my node.js app it worked out of the box.

After that, I downscaled it to a free tier and it still works now(fingers crossed). This might help for students struggling with socket io on azure.